# How to fetch top 10 channel with youtube api

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-analytics-api

Hello I'm am now on a project that using YouTube api,
I am bit of stuck on how to fetch top 10 channel of a **content owner** at YouTube by using their api. 
Right now what i am doing is that i need to loop all the channel i had and sort it by their views.

```
loop {

$analytics = $youtube->reports->query('contentOwner==$content_id', $start_date , $end_date , 'views,comments,likes,dislikes,estimatedMinutesWatched,averageViewDuration,shares,estimatedRevenue,estimatedAdRevenue,monetizedPlaybacks,adImpressions',array('filters'=> $id ,'max-results'=>$max_result));

}
```

It is fine but as it need to loop all the channel it takes quite some time. Is there any other way to fetch top 10 channel directly ?

By the way, is there any other way to by pass user consent?

Comment: You taged this Youtube api but the call you are using is for YouTube Analayitcs  API which api are you using exactly? Can you clean up your question / code.

Comment: there are 3 youtube api , which is analytics, data, and reporting . i used data in order to get the channel list, but to get the views etc i used youtube analytics api. i just tagged it to youtube api.

Comment: The code you have included  $youtube->reports->query  is reporting api is your question  about reporting api if so please fix your tags.  if not change your code to reflect the api the question is about.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

problem solved after i do a lot of try and error,
youtube provide an api explorer for developer to test query parameter right away.

[image: youtube api explorer]

as i explain in the question i had successfully able to fetch/retrieve the data for a channel by using loop.

actually i can just put every channel id with comma to retrieve all the channel i manage.

before PHP example

```
 loop {


    $id = 'channel==' . $id;

        $analytics = $youtube->reports->query('contentOwner==$content_id', $start_date , $end_date , 'views,comments,likes,dislikes,estimatedMinutesWatched,averageViewDuration,shares,estimatedRevenue,estimatedAdRevenue,monetizedPlaybacks,adImpressions',array('filters'=> $id ,'max-results'=>$max_result));

}
```

new or solved php example

```
$id = 'channel==' . implode(',', $id);
$analytics = $youtube->reports->query('contentOwner==$content_id', $start_date , $end_date,'views,comments,likes,dislikes,estimatedMinutesWatched,averageViewDuration,shares,estimatedRevenue,estimatedAdRevenue,monetizedPlaybacks,adImpressions',array('filters'=> $id ,'max-results'=>$max_result));
```

youtube already give the documentation on how to use their api, but i think it is quite hard to understand. Therefore i am able to use the api only when i do alot of try and error.

Thank you.